# tex4ht fails on including image with math in caption after loading hyperref package

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht

This MWE compiles OK with lualatex but fails in tex4ht once `hyperref` is added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Phase plot $y^{\prime \prime}\left(t \right)+9 y \left(t \right)-\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
8 \sin \left(t \right) & 0<t <\pi  
\\
 0 & \pi <t  
\end{array}\right.\right) = 0$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And now

```
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug  foo.tex "mathjax,htm"
```

gives

```
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./foo.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
[1] [2]
l.9 --- TeX4ht warning --- File `"example-image-a.xbb"' not found ---
l.9 --- TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in "example-image-a
.xbb" (no BoundingBox) ---
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \EndPicture 
            
l.14 \end{array}\right.\right) = 0$}
                                  
?
```

Removing `hyperref` it compiles clean. (ps. I used test image above so it can compile as is). Same error is generated with a real image file.

Is there a workaround for this?

TL 2022 on Linux

Fyi, [link to ticket](https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/index.php?587) add.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you write `y^{\prime \prime}`, when `y''` is both simpler and clearer? What is the purpose of writing `\left(t \right)` instead of `(t)`?

Comment: @Mico the math is auto-generated by Maple. I just put the Latex translation of the equation there. This is how all CAS systems generate Latex. Same for left and right.

Comment: Hope `\caption[]{...}` also will works, but not yet tested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that `\begin` and `\end` are redefined by TeX4ht, but not as robust commands. When you load Hyperref, expanded contents of `\caption` are saved in a macro for further processing, which leads to this error. The fix is to declare `\begin` and `\end` as robust commands. The fixed `latex.4ht` is too huge to be posted here, but you can use this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter

\DeclareRobustCommand\begin[1]{\csname @begin:#1\endcsname
  \choose:begin
    {\let\choose:begin\@firstoftwo \ifx \EndPicture\:Undef
   \PushStack\envn:list\n:list  \SaveEverypar
\fi
\let\chk:pic\EndPicture
\ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef  \list:save
\let\after:end\empty   \csname before:begin#1\endcsname   \fi
%
\UseHook{env/#1/before}%
\@ifundefined{#1}%
  {\def\reserved@a{\@latex@error{Environment #1 undefined}\@eha}}%
  {\def\reserved@a{%
          \def\@currenvir{#1}%
          \edef\@currenvline{\on@line}%
          \ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef
   \ifx \this:listConfigure\empty
       \null:listConfigure  \csname on#1:list\endcsname \fi
\fi
%
          \@execute@begin@hook{#1}%
          \csname #1\endcsname
                         %
%
  }}%
\global\@ignorefalse
\begingroup
  \@endpefalse
  \reserved@a
}%
    {\o:begin:{#1}}}

\DeclareRobustCommand\end[1]{\choose:begin
  {%\IgnoreIndent
  \ifvmode \ifx \EndPicture\:UnDef
   \def\:temp{\def\:temp{%
   \def\:temp{\IgnorePar
     \ifx \:tempa\hline \expandafter\\\else\fi
   }%
   \futurelet\:tempa\:temp
}%
%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\:temp}%
   \expandafter\:temp
\fi
\fi
\UseHook{env/#1/end}%
\csname end#1\endcsname%
\@checkend{#1}%
  \aftergroup\recall:afterend
\expandafter\endgroup\if@endpe\@doendpe\fi
\UseHook{env/#1/after}%
  \ifx \chk:pic\:UnDef
     \csname after:end\endcsname
\expandafter\let\csname after:end\endcsname\:UnDef
%
     \PopStack\envn:list\:tempb
\ifnum \:tempb=\n:list \else
   \def\:temp{#1}\def\:tempa{thebibliography}\ifx \:temp\:tempa
   \else\:warning{\string\SaveEverypar's: \:tempb\space at
          \string\begin{#1} and \n:list\space \string\end{#1}}%
\fi \fi
%
     \list:recall
  \else
     \let\chk:pic\:UnDef
  \fi
\if@ignore\global\@ignorefalse\ignorespaces\fi
}%
  {\o:end:{#1}}}
\makeatother
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

I will also fix it in the TeX4ht sources, so it will be unnecessary after TeX Live update soon.

This is the result:

[image]