# Error converting Latex to HTML - package algorithm2e?

Tags: algorithm2e, html, htlatex

## Update

I've reduced the entire thesis down to an empty doc with the packages that I'm using.

I've tried commenting out each of the packages one by one, and including them one by one, and the results are:

- if I **include all** of the packages **except** `algorithm2e`, htlatex works without error
- if I **comment out all** of the packages and **include only** `algorithm2e`, htlatex works without error
- if I comment out random selections of packages, and include `algorithm2e` along with a random selection of packages, htlatex still works without error
- if I include all packages as is, htlatex gives the error

```
! Argument of \boolean has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
```

So it seems the package `algorithm2e` might be causing an issue. But on its own, and even in conjunction with a random selection of other packages, it works. It's only when it's included along with everything else does the error seem to creep up. With 22 packages, I can't test every possible combination of packages so I'm hoping somebody might have a theoretical guess as to what's happening and how to get around this?

Note, PDF building works fine. It's only htlatex which is giving problems.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for the inclusion of images
\usepackage[font=small,skip=10pt]{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage[algoruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

---

## Original post

I'd like to convert my PhD thesis (80K+ words, 250+ pages, multiple tex files, loads of references and figures and equations and packages) to html with anchors. **Ideally** it would be like an online manual with each chapter - or even each section within each chapter - its own html file with navigation on the side (e.g. ref https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html )

But before I even get that far, I'd be happy to have any preliminary html conversion even if everything was in a single html file!

I found many threads about this online, and tried `htlatex my_thesis_master.tex` but I'm getting an error

```
(C:\Users\memoa\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\tex/latex/apacite\english.apc)
! Argument of \boolean has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.117 \begin{document}
```

From TexStudio I can build a PDF and it looks fine, though there are some warnings. The warnings seem to be about references in my bib file, but my bib was automatically exported from Mendeley, and all references seem correct in the PDF. In fact the PDF is fine.

Unfortunately I'm not proficient enough with the LaTeX ecosystem to figure out what's going wrong and why I can't export from tex to html.

Below I've included some info.

I'm on Windows 11. TexStudio with MiKTeX updated.

## LaTeX system report (From TexStudio)

```
dpi: 96
where pdflatex: C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe

PDFLATEX: pdflatex.exe -version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 4.13 (MiKTeX 22.12)
Â© 1982 D. E. Knuth, Â© 1996-2022 HÃ n Tháº¿ ThÃ nh
TeX is a trademark of the American Mathematical Society.
using bzip2 version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019
compiled with curl version 7.72.0; using libcurl/7.72.0 Schannel
compiled with expat version 2.2.10; using expat_2.2.10
compiled with jpeg version 9.4
compiled with liblzma version 50020052; using 50020052
compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
compiled with libressl version LibreSSL 3.1.4; using LibreSSL 3.1.4
compiled with MiKTeX Application Framework version 4.6; using 4.6
compiled with MiKTeX Core version 4.16; using 4.16
compiled with MiKTeX Archive Extractor version 4.0; using 4.0
compiled with MiKTeX Package Manager version 4.8; using 4.8
compiled with uriparser version 0.9.4
compiled with xpdf version 4.02
compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11

TeXstudio:
Path        : C:\Program Files\texstudio\texstudio.exe
Program call: C:\Program Files\texstudio\texstudio.exe
Setting file: C:\Users\memoa\AppData\Roaming\texstudio\texstudio.ini

Command configuration in TeXstudio:
    DVI->PS->PDF Chain (dvi-ps-pdf-chain): txs:///latex | txs:///dvips | txs:///ps2pdf | txs:///view-pdf
    Latexmk (latexmk): latexmk.exe -pdf -silent -synctex=1 %
    External Terminal (terminal-external): C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
    LuaLaTeX (lualatex) (r): lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
    Default Compiler (compile) (r): txs:///pdflatex
    DVI->PDF Chain (dvi-pdf-chain): txs:///latex | txs:///dvipdf | txs:///view-pdf
    DviPdf (dvipdf): dvipdfmx.exe %.dvi
    Makeindex (makeindex): makeindex.exe %.idx
    PS Chain (ps-chain): txs:///latex | txs:///dvips | txs:///view-ps
    Asymptote DVI Chain (asy-dvi-chain): txs:///latex | txs:///asy | txs:///latex | txs:///view-dvi
    Makeglossaries (makeglossaries): makeglossaries.exe %
    Recompile Bibliography (recompile-bibliography): txs:///compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile
    Asymptote (asy): asy.exe ?m*.asy
    DviPng (dvipng): dvipng.exe -T tight -D 120 %.dvi
    XeLaTeX (xelatex) (r): xelatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
    Xindex (xindex): xindex.exe -l * %.idx
    Default Glossary Tool (glossary): txs:///makeglossaries
    SVNADMIN (svnadmin): 
    Precompile (pre-compile): 
    Texindy (texindy): texindy.exe %.idx
    Default Viewer (view): txs:///view-pdf
    DVI Viewer (view-dvi): C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\yap.exe -1 -s @?"c:ame "?am.dvi"
    External PDF Viewer (view-pdf-external): "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" "?am.pdf"
    Asymptote PDF Chain (asy-pdf-chain): txs:///pdflatex | txs:///asy | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf
    MetaPost (metapost): mpost.exe -interaction=nonstopmode ?me)
    Default Index Tool (index): txs:///makeindex
    Build & View (quick): txs:///compile | txs:///view
    PdfLaTeX (pdflatex) (r): pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
    LaTeX (latex) (r): latex.exe -src -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
    texdoc (texdoc): texdoc.exe 
    Ps2Pdf (ps2pdf): ps2pdf.exe %.ps
    DVI Chain (dvi-chain): txs:///latex | txs:///view-dvi
    Biber (biber): biber.exe %
    PDF Viewer (view-pdf): txs:///view-pdf-internal --embedded
    GIT (git): git.exe 
    PDF Chain (pdf-chain): txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf
    DviPs (dvips): dvips.exe -o %.ps %.dvi
    Default Bibliography Tool (bibliography): txs:///bibtex
    PS Viewer (view-ps): C:\Windows\system32\OpenWith.exe "?am.ps"
    BibTeX (bibtex): bibtex.exe %
    Internal Precompile (internal-pre-compile): txs:///pre-compile | txs:///conditionally-recompile-bibliography
    BibTeX 8-Bit (bibtex8): bibtex8.exe %
    SVN (svn): 
    Ghostscript (gs): mgs.exe "?am.ps"

Additional Search Paths:
    Command: 
    Log: 
    Pdf:
```

## master tex file

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
%\usepackage{siunitx} % Provides the \SI{}{} and \si{} command for typesetting SI units
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for the inclusion of images
\usepackage[font=small,skip=10pt]{caption}
%\usepackage{natbib} % Required to change bibliography style to APA
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{breakcites}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{epigraph}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[algoruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
%\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
%\usepackage{program} 
%\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e} 
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color,soul}

% for python code, from https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-optimal-way-to-include-Python-code-in-a-LaTeX-document?share=1
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{listings}

% NOTE: Add date and time to every page for drafts
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%\pagestyle{headings}
\lhead{\rightmark}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{Page \thepage}
%\cfoot{Compiled on \today\ at \currenttime}
\rfoot{}
\raggedbottom

% For notes 
\usepackage{todonotes}
%\usepackage[disable]{todonotes} % Disables notes

\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfsetup{hidealllines=true,backgroundcolor=yellow!25!white}

\newenvironment{newbits}
{
    \begin{mdframed}
    }
    {
    \end{mdframed}
}



\bibliographystyle{apacite}


\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

% Math utils
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
\newcommand{\diag}{\text{diag}}
\newcommand{\bm}[1]{{\boldsymbol{#1}}} % Bold math symbol (use for vectors and matrices)
\newcommand{\trsp}{{\!\scriptscriptstyle\top}} 
\newcommand{\psin}{{\!\dagger}} % Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse 
\newcommand{\tp}[1]{\text{\tiny#1}}
\newcommand{\ty}[1]{{\scriptscriptstyle\mathcal{#1}}} 
\newcommand{\tr}{\text{tr}} %trace
\newcommand{\cov}{\text{cov}} 
\newcommand{\new}{{\!\scriptscriptstyle\text{new}}}
\newcommand{\reals}{{\rm I\!R}} % Real numbers
\newcommand{\trans}{{\mathsf{T}}} % Transpose symbol
\newcommand{\refeq}[1]{{eqn. (\ref{#1})}} % Ref to equation
\newcommand{\refig}[1]{{Fig. \ref{#1}}} % Ref to figure
\newcommand{\refalg}[1]{{Alg. \ref{#1}}} % Ref to algorithm
\newcommand{\refsect}[1]{{Section \ref{#1}}} % Ref to section
\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1}: \textit{\nameref*{#1}}}} % One single link
\newcommand*{\secref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1}}} % One single link


\renewcommand{\vec}{\bm} % for vectors
\newcommand{\matr}{\bm} % for matrices
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\newcommand\given[1][]{\:#1\vert\:}

\newcommand{\x}         {\vec{x}} 
\newcommand{\xp}        {\vec{x'}} 
\newcommand{\xhat}      {\vec{\hat{y}}} 
\newcommand{\y}         {\vec{y}} 
\newcommand{\yp}        {\vec{y'}} 
\newcommand{\yhat}      {\vec{\hat{y}}} 
\newcommand{\z}         {\vec{z}} 
\newcommand{\h}         {\vec{h}} 
\newcommand{\vc}        {\vec{c}} 
\newcommand{\vb}        {\vec{b}} 
\newcommand{\W}         {\matr{W}} 
\newcommand{\mTheta}    {\matr{\Theta}} 
\newcommand{\vmu}       {\vec{\mu}} 
\newcommand{\vsigma}    {\vec{\sigma}} 
\newcommand{\E}         {\mathbb{E}}




\onehalfspacing
\begin{document}

\author{Memo Akten}
\title{Deep Visual Instruments: Realtime Continuous, Meaningful Human Control over Deep Neural Networks for creative expression}
\date{September 2020}

\frontmatter

    
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{\fill} 
        
        \Huge
        Deep Visual Instruments: \\
        \LARGE
        Realtime Continuous, 
        Meaningful Human Control \\
        over Deep Neural Networks 
        for Creative Expression
        
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
    
%       \Large
        Mehmet Selim Akten
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.12\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{figures/MSA_HEAD_1024}
        \end{figure}


        
%       \bigskip
%       \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \bigskip    
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
        \bigskip        
        \bigskip
        \bigskip        
        \bigskip
        
        \normalsize     
A dissertation submitted in partial fulfillment \\
of the requirements for the degree of \\
\textbf{Doctor of Philosophy} \\
        \bigskip

\textbf{Goldsmiths, University of London} \\
Department of Computing     \\
        
%       Thesis submitted to \\
%       \textbf{Goldsmiths University of London} \\
%       \bigskip
%       for the Degree of\\
%       \textbf{Doctor of Philosophy}
%       
        \bigskip
%       Advisors:\\
%       Mick Grierson \\
%       Rebecca Fiebrink
        
        \bigskip
        \bigskip
        April 2021 \\
%       Draft compiled on \today\ at \currenttime
        \vspace{\fill}  
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}


%Declaration of Authorship

I, Mehmet Selim Akten, hereby declare that this thesis and the work presented in it is entirely my own. Where I have consulted the work of others, this is always clearly stated. 

\bigskip
\bigskip    

Signed: 
\bigskip
\bigskip    

Date: 22 April, 2021
\bigskip
\bigskip    

\clearpage

% dedication
\include{abstract}
\include{acknowledgements}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
%\listoftables
\listofalgorithms\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of algorithms}


\mainmatter
\include{introduction}
\include{background}
\include{seq}
\include{helloworld}
\include{learningtosee}
\include{deepmeditations}
%\include{zexplore}
%\include{grannma}
%\include{3d}
\include{conclusion}
%apendices

\backmatter
\bibliography{bib/library}
% glossary
% list of acronyms
% index

\end{document}
```

## Messages from building PDF in TexStudio

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "MemoAkten_PhDThesis"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 22.12)
The top-level auxiliary file: MemoAkten_PhDThesis.aux
The style file: apacite.bst
Database file #1: bib/library.bib
Repeated entry---line 11800 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Colton2012
 :                    ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 12041 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Dong2016
 :                  ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 13272 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Zaremba2014
 :                     ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 13625 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Mccormack2012
 :                       ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 15924 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Wang2014
 :                  ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 18259 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Boden1998
 :                   ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 23263 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{McCormack2014
 :                       ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
apacite.bst [2013/07/21 v6.03 APA bibliography style]
Warning--No journal in Akten2015-ofxMSAmcts
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Akten2015-ofxMSAmcts
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Arjovsky2017
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Arjovsky2017
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No address in bellman1957markovian
Warning--No journal in Berthelot2017
Warning--No journal in Bishop1994
Warning--No journal in Brown2020
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Brown2020
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Cavallo2013
Warning--No journal in Chen2016
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Chen2016
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Cohen1994
Warning--No journal in Cui2017
Warning--No journal in Deng2013a
Warning--No journal in Dhariwal2020
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Dhariwal2020
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Dinh2016
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Dinh2016
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Dong2016
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Dong2016
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Dosovitskiy2015
Warning--No journal in Goodfellow2014
Warning--No school in Graves2008
Warning--No journal in Gwak2017
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Gwak2017
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Ha2017sketchrnn
Warning--No journal in Harkonen2020
Warning--No journal in Huval2015
Warning--No journal in Jiang2020
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Jiang2020
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Karras2020
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Karras2020
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Kingma2018Glow
Warning--No journal in Liang2017
Warning--No journal in Liu2017b
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Liu2017b
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Mahendran2014
Warning--No journal in McCormack2014
Warning--No address in McNeill1980
Warning--No journal in Miolane2018
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Miolane2018
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Nayebi2015
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Nayebi2015
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Rezende2016
Warning--No journal in Rezende2018
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Rezende2018
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Ridgeway2016
Warning--No institution in Roff2016
Wa
rning--No address in Roff2016
Warning--No institution in rumelhart1985learning
Warning--No address in rumelhart1985learning
Warning--No journal in Salimans2016
Warning--No journal in Santoro2016
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Santoro2016
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Tresset2014
Warning--No journal in Wu2016b
Warning--No journal in Ermon2017
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Ermon2017
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
(There were 23 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "MemoAkten_PhDThesis".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: bibtex.exe "MemoAkten_PhDThesis"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 22.12)
The top-level auxiliary file: MemoAkten_PhDThesis.aux
The style file: apacite.bst
Database file #1: bib/library.bib
Repeated entry---line 11800 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Colton2012
 :                    ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 12041 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Dong2016
 :                  ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 13272 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Zaremba2014
 :                     ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 13625 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Mccormack2012
 :                       ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 15924 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Wang2014
 :                  ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 18259 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{Boden1998
 :                   ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
Repeated entry---line 23263 of file bib/library.bib
 : @article{McCormack2014
 :                       ,
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry
apacite.bst [2013/07/21 v6.03 APA bibliography style]
Warning--No journal in Akten2015-ofxMSAmcts
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Akten2015-ofxMSAmcts
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Arjovsky2017
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Arjovsky2017
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No address in bellman1957markovian
Warning--No journal in Berthelot2017
Warning--No journal in Bishop1994
Warning--No journal in Brown2020
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Brown2020
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Cavallo2013
Warning--No journal in Chen2016
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Chen2016
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Cohen1994
Warning--No journal in Cui2017
Warning--No journal in Deng2013a
Warning--No journal in Dhariwal2020
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Dhariwal2020
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Dinh2016
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Dinh2016
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Dong2016
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Dong2016
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Dosovitskiy2015
Warning--No journal in Goodfellow2014
Warning--No school in Graves2008
Warning--No journal in Gwak2017
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Gwak2017
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Ha2017sketchrnn
Warning--No journal in Harkonen2020
Warning--No journal in Huval2015
Warning--No journal in Jiang2020
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Jiang2020
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Karras2020
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Karras2020
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Kingma2018Glow
Warning--No journal in Liang2017
Warning--No journal in Liu2017b
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Liu2017b
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Mahendran2014
Warning--No journal in McCormack2014
Warning--No address in McNeill1980
Warning--No journal in Miolane2018
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Miolane2018
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Nayebi2015
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Nayebi2015
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Rezende2016
Warning--No journal in Rezende2018
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Rezende2018
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Ridgeway2016
Warning--No institution in Roff2016
Wa
rning--No address in Roff2016
Warning--No institution in rumelhart1985learning
Warning--No address in rumelhart1985learning
Warning--No journal in Salimans2016
Warning--No journal in Santoro2016
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Santoro2016
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
Warning--No journal in Tresset2014
Warning--No journal in Wu2016b
Warning--No journal in Ermon2017
ptr=1, stack=

---the literal stack isn't empty for entry Ermon2017
while executing---line 5079 of file apacite.bst
(There were 23 error messages)
Process exited with error(s)


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "MemoAkten_PhDThesis".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "MemoAkten_PhDThesis".tex

Process exited normally
```

Comment: The code you provided is both too long (contains a lot of code unrelated to the problem) and incomplete (very likely doesn't contain the part triggering the problem). As with any programming language, start by removing almost everything, and re-add code little by little until the problem reappears. This way you'll be able to build a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that you'll be able to post here.

Comment: @Miyase ok i've posted a minimal (non-)working example

Comment: That's better, thanks. However, your code still can't be tested by anyone, since you include several other files that you don't provide. The point is that people can copy-paste your code and try to compile it themselves. Keep trimming the code to isolate the problem.

Comment: With your new empty document I can't reproduce the problem, either with `htlatex` (which is no longer the recommended way of compiling although it still works) or with `make4ht`, both of them produce html without any errors. Maybe your system is too new, there have been some issues with the latest updates (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/669581/ for example). But in any case there is no fundamental incompatibility between this set of packages and tex4ht, so that is positive I guess :)

Comment: Regarding further debugging: of course you can't test every combination of those 22 packages, but you can try removing them one by one, starting at the top. If the issue disappears then leave that package in (so the issue re-appears) and remove the next package. This will probably narrow down the list of involved packages rather quickly.

Comment: I've tried your example with up-to date TeX Live, as well as the development version of TeX4ht, and I cannot replicate this issue. It seems that this issue is caused by some package that had been fixed in the meantime. So the best thing you can do is to update your TeX distribution. Unfortunately, MikTeX has sometimes older version of TeX4ht files, because updates are not included on CTAN. You can try to post a bug report to https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/ to let MikTex's maintainer know that it needs to be updated.