# tex4ht fails when adding \centering after \begin{figure}

Tags: tex4ht

This is related to [tex4ht fails on including image with math in caption after loading hyperref package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669581/tex4ht-fails-on-including-image-with-math-in-caption-after-loading-hyperref-pack) but fails under new conditions.

This is summary of what is going on. There was a bug in the above link where tex4ht failed when adding math in the caption of the image when `hyperref` was loaded. Thanks to michal.h21 this is fixed now in latest TL as I no longer get the error using the MWE in the above, which is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Phase plot $y^{\prime \prime}\left(t \right)+9 y \left(t \right)-\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
8 \sin \left(t \right) & 0<t <\pi  
\\
 0 & \pi <t  
\end{array}\right.\right) = 0$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Using the command

```
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug  foo.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

No errors. Great. But once I added `\centering`, similar error came back from the same location of the file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Phase plot $y^{\prime \prime}\left(t \right)+9 y \left(t \right)-\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
8 \sin \left(t \right) & 0<t <\pi  
\\
 0 & \pi <t  
\end{array}\right.\right) = 0$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And now the same command

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug  foo.tex 'mathjax,htm'
```

Gives

```
[INFO]    mkparams: Output dir: 
[INFO]    mkparams: Compiler: dvilualatex
[INFO]    mkparams: Latex options: -jobname='foo'  
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht.sty: xhtml,mathjax,htm,charset=utf-8
[INFO]    mkparams: tex4ht:  -cmozhtf -utf8
[INFO]    mkparams: build_file: foo.mk4
[INFO]    mkparams: Output format: html5
[STATUS]  make4ht: Conversion started
....
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/unicode.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html4-math.4ht)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/html5.4ht))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./foo.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)17 nil

[1] [2]
l.10 --- TeX4ht warning --- File `"example-image-a.xbb"' not found ---
l.10 --- TeX4ht warning --- Cannot determine size of graphic in "example-image-
a.xbb" (no BoundingBox) ---
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
\par 
l.15 \end{array}\right.\right) = 0$}
                                  
?
```

Which is the similar error to the one fixed in the earlier question linked above which was

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \EndPicture 
            
l.14 \end{array}\right.\right) = 0$}
```

The above example compiles OK with lualatex giving

[image]

Any workaround for this new problem as I use `\centering` in my code.

TL 2022 Updated just 1/2 hr ago.

```
>which make4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/make4ht
>make4ht --version
make4ht version v0.3l
>which tex4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tex4ht
```

**Update**

Thanks for the comment below by MadyYuvi, using `\caption[short caption]{long caption with the math}` makes tex4ht not give compile error. Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption[Phase plot]{Phase plot $y^{\prime \prime}\left(t \right)+9 y \left(t \right)-\left(\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
8 \sin \left(t \right) & 0<t <\pi  
\\
 0 & \pi <t  
\end{array}\right.\right) = 0$}
\end{figure}
```

Now it compiles OK using same command. Still, I think tex4ht should not give an error as before, but this can be used as a workaround for now.

[Link to tracking](http://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?590)

Comment: If you don't want the caption in `LOF`, hope then `\caption[]{...}` will works, but not sure, just a try

Comment: @MadyYuvi thanks for the suggestion. Yes this is a good workaround. Will add it as example. But I think tex4ht should still work with the math in there.

Comment: Thanks for your kind words, Yes I agree with you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the `\centering` command redefines `\\`, and this fails with TeX4ht's support for Nameref (which is required by Hyperref). This can be fixed using this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]{%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \begingroup%
    \let\index\:gobble%
    \let\label\:gobble%
    \let\\\relax
    \protected@xdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#2}}%
    \endgroup%
   \o:NR@@caption{#1}[{#2}]%
}
\makeatother
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

In short, we need to disable the `\\` when we define the `\NR:Title` command. It will not affect the rendering of the document, it is used only for the Nameref's purposes.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michal. Would this fix become part of official tex4ht sources or do I need to keep this configuration in my .cfg all the time?

Comment: @Nasser yes, it will be included in sources. I will probably make a configuration to pass redefinitions of commands for caption